# How to fix Call to a member function isAdmin() on null

Tags: php, laravel, admin, roles

I have  a route :
Route::get('/TransactionHistory','QuoteController@transactionHistory');

In Controller QuoteController, I have a function as:

```
public function transactionHistory(){
         if(Auth::user()->isAdmin())
        {
               $res= DB::table('products_products')
->select('users_users.display_name','products_products.name','products_products.id','products_products.user_id','products_products.quantity_type','buy_product.price','buy_product.rating','buy_product.mileage_name','buy_product.id as buy_id')
->join('buy_product','products_products.id','=','buy_product.product_id')
->join('users_users','buy_product.user_id','=','users_users.id')
->get();
        }
        else{
       $u_id=auth()->user()->id;
      $res= DB::table('products_products')
->select('products_products.name','products_products.id','products_products.user_id','products_products.quantity_type','buy_product.price','buy_product.rating','buy_product.mileage_name','buy_product.id as buy_id')
->join('buy_product','products_products.id','=','buy_product.product_id')

->where('buy_product.user_id','=',$u_id)
->get();}
        
    return view('templates::pagetwigs/transaction-history')->with('details',$res);
    }
```

On routing the path I got error as :**Call to a member function isAdmin() on null**

How to fix this.

Comment: You need to define isAdmin() on the User model. Are  you define it ?

Comment: so this function is in `User` model `(User.php)`. you can modify it from there or you can just add an another condition `if( auth()->check() && Auth::user()->isAdmin() )`. this error because of user not login I think so.

Comment: @Abdullah Al Mamun I dont have user model

Comment: @Binsha User.php is the user model and its default with Laravel. You can find it app/User.php

Comment: Your error is saying `Auth::user()` is `null`; did you login? If you ever reference the `auth()->user()` method (or `Auth::user()`), you need to make sure you've actually logged in, otherwise your code will fail. Or check it before referencing via `if(auth()->user() && auth()->user()->isAdmin())`, etc.

Comment: @Bappi Saha . How to check for admin role without user model?

Comment: @Tim Lewis How to redirect to homepage if not admin or user?

Comment: Wrap any routes that call this code in a Middleware that redirects to the login page if no user is logged in. This is all in the Documentation, have a look over there: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authentication#protecting-routes

Comment: @Binsha then you have to use custom middleware as Tim Lewis said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add middleware in the route or in the constructor of controller as shown:

```
public function __construct()
{
      $this->middleware('auth');
    
}
```

This will not allow you to access the page unless you are logged in . This will  always check that `Auth::user()` is not null